# unpivot (wide to long) with dynamic column names

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need a function `wide_to_long` that turns a wide table into a long table and that accepts an argument `id_vars` for which the values have to be repeated (see example).

**Sample input**

```
let T_wide = datatable(name: string, timestamp: datetime, A: int, B: int) [ 
'abc','2022-01-01 12:00:00',1,2,
'def','2022-01-01 13:00:00',3,4
];
```

[image]

**Desired output**

Calling `wide_to_long(T_wide, dynamic(['name', 'timestamp']))` should produce the following table.

```
let T_long = datatable(name: string, timestamp: datetime, variable: string, value: int) [ 
'abc','2022-01-01 12:00:00','A',1,
'abc','2022-01-01 12:00:00','B',2,
'def','2022-01-01 13:00:00','A',3,
'def','2022-01-01 13:00:00','B',4
];
```

[image]

**Attempt**

I've come pretty far with the following code.

```
let wide_to_long = (T:(*), id_vars: dynamic) {
    // get names of keys to remove later
    let all_columns = toscalar(T | getschema | summarize make_list(ColumnName));
    let remove = set_difference(all_columns, id_vars);
    // expand columns not contained in id_vars
    T
    | extend packed1 = pack_all()
    | extend packed1 = bag_remove_keys(packed1, id_vars)
    | mv-expand kind=array packed1
    | extend variable = packed1[0], value = packed1[1]
    // remove unwanted columns
    | project packed2 = pack_all()
    | project packed2 = bag_remove_keys(packed2, remove)
    | evaluate bag_unpack(packed2)
    | project-away packed1
};
```

The problems are that the solution feels clunky (is there a better way?) and the columns in the result are ordered randomly. The second issue is minor, but annoying.

Comment: (1) The operation is called unpivot (2) Do you really "need a function"? (3) Not randomly, arbitrarily. Depends on an internal implementation.

Comment: (1) cool (2) yes, I need to unpivot lots of tables with update policies and don't want to repeat code (3) no practical difference

Comment: My bad. Since I got wrong the content of id_vars, I mistakenly thought that your solution does not work.